# Sending/Storing Data from Multiple Users in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I plan to embed a .swf within an online survey that will be taken by multiple users at once. This .swf currently contains a button that should (upon each click of the button) send the current values of a collection of variables (numbers, strings, and arrays) from AS3 to an external file (e.g. CSV) - creating an entry (i.e. a row) within this file containing the values of these variables, marked with a userID (which may begin as one of the variables in AS3).

I am new to web programming, so I plan to teach myself whatever is necessary to accomplish this. Given my goals, what would be the simplest and most effective way to go about doing this?

One issue I'm concerned about is the possibility of "colliding edits" to the storage destination file, since multiple edits could potentially be made within a fairly short time interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your backend system create a user idea for each row and return it in the response.
Have then flash store the userId and append it to each new request.
if a request comes with a userId == "" then you know it's a new user, else you know what userId to be updated.
You may save the userId in a cookie, or a flash cookie or just keepit within your flash instance depending on either you need the id to remain on refresh or not.
It's a pretty basic explanation but that should get you started.